# why does the program give me this message: 'Program halted for running too long'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this problem :

> The number 81 has a special property, a certain power of the sum of
>   its digits is equal to 81 (nine squared). Eighty one (81), is the
>   first number in having this property (not considering numbers of one
>   digit). The next one, is 512. Let's see both cases with the details
>
> ```
> 8 + 1 = 9 and 9^2 = 81
>
> 512 = 5 + 1 + 2 = 8 and 8^3 = 512
> ```

We need to make a function, `power_sumDigTerm()`, that receives a number n and may output the `n-th` term of this sequence of numbers. The cases we presented above means that : 
so I have solved the problem as below;

```
function findPow(sum,i) {
   var counter = 0;
   while (true) {
     counter++;
     if (Math.pow(sum,counter) === i) {
         return true;
     } else if (Math.pow(sum,counter) > i) {
        return false;
     }
   }
}

function powerSumDigTerm(n) {
  var index = 80;
  var result = [];
    function loop() {
      index++;
      var sum = 0;
      var string = index.toString();
      for (var i =0;i<string.length;i++) {
        sum += Number(string[i]);
      }
      if (findPow(sum,index)) {
      result.push(index);
      }
      return (n === result.length) ? result[n-1] : loop()
    }
  return loop()
}
```

here is the problem, when I ran the function and pass in 1 `powerSumDigTerm(1)`. The output would be 81 as expected. However, if we pass in 2  ,`console.log(powerSumDigTerm(2))` , the function returns a message saying : `Program halted for running too long, sorry!` Does anyone have any explanation why the function does that ? and how to avoid it ?

Comment: There is a fault in your programming logir that never go out the while loop. You need to fix the IF clause.

Comment: Do you mean in the findPow function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is within your `findPow` function.

Consider the case of 100. Where the sum is 1 and 1 raised to power of any number will result into 1 i.e. `i ^ x == 1`. So, you need to handle a special case of 1 in order to fix the problem.

```
if (sum <= 1) return false;
```

Further, you are using recursion that will soon throw `StackOverflow` exception. I tested below solution and that works for `n = 15`. As complexity grows exponentially, calculating higher number requires a much-optimized solution.

```js
function findPow(sum, i) {
    if (sum <= 1) return;
    var counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        counter++;
        if (Math.pow(sum, counter) === i) {
            return true;
        } else if (Math.pow(sum, counter) > i) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function powerSumDigTerm(n) {
    var index = 80;
    var result = [];

    function next() {
        index++;
        var sum = 0;
        var string = index.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            sum += Number(string[i]);
        }
        if (findPow(sum, index)) {
            result.push(index);
        }
    }
    while (result.length < n)
        next()

    return result[n - 1];
}

console.log('1:', powerSumDigTerm(1));
console.log('2:', powerSumDigTerm(2));
console.log('5:', powerSumDigTerm(5));
console.log('10:', powerSumDigTerm(10));
```

Comment: Your explanation is great, I just ran your solution, but the program still give me this message : 'Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete'. It is from coderwars.com

Answer (score 0):

As @Adnan has pointed out, there is an issue in your `findPow()` function where it will enter an infinite loop if `sum` is 1, and you also have a risk of a stack overflow error.

There's really no sense in using recursion here when a simple loop would do. You should also avoid `while(true)` loops which are usually just a sign of laziness:

```js
function findPow(sum, i) {
  for (var pow = 0; sum > 1 && Math.pow(sum, pow) <= i; pow += 1) {
    if (Math.pow(sum, pow) === i) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function sumDigits(number) {
  var sum = 0;
  var str = number.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(str[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

function powerSumDigTerm(n) {
  var result = [];

  for (var index = 1; result.length < n; index += 1) {
    if (findPow(sumDigits(index), index)) {
      result.push(index);
    }
  }

  return result[n - 1];
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i += 1) {
  console.log(i, powerSumDigTerm(i));
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is great, I just ran your solution, but the program still give me this message : 'Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete'. It is from coderwars.com

Comment: Did you remove the `for` loop at the end? That was just for demonstration purposes.